# Add subtitle to category list magento 2

Tags: php, xml

For my magento2 store I want to have a subtitle right beneath the Title the product.

Right now I have it working for the "product overview" with the next code:

I added this code to: `catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<referenceBlock name="category.product.addto">
    <block class="" name="category.subtitle" template="product/view/subtitle.phtml" />
</referenceBlock>
```

I created a new `subtitle.phtml` with the next code in it:

```
<h3><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProduct()->getResource()->getAttribute('subtitle1')->getFrontend()->getValue($block->getProduct()); ?></h3>
```

But i do not know how to get it working in the category list.

Is there someone who can help me with it?

UPDATE:

the attribute i created has the right settings (used in product listing is enabled)

the code i am using is:

```
<referenceBlock name="product-item-details"> <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="category.subtitle" template="product/view/subtitle.phtml" /> </referenceBlock>
i placed this code in "catalog_product_view.xml
```

Im notting getting the subtitle right beneath my title in the grid view / category view.

i think there must be something wrong with the code from the reference block but i cannot figure out where the problem is .

thanks! regards Mark

Answer (score 0):

How is your attribute setuped. Check the attributes settings because attributes can be hidden. 
Your code should work with following:

Make sure **“Visible on Product View Page on Front-end”** and **“Used in Product Listing”** options under storefront Properties are set to Yes.

This is a quick guess because your code should work, so please check your settings of custom attribute. If it still doesn't show up can you please provide more details